# R List of the prefix of a files list

Tags: r, list, prefix

I am trying to make a list of the prefix of files in a directory. I have about 45 files having the same prefix, for example:

`AH#01, AH#02... AH#45`

then

`BH#01, BH#02...`

I am trying to make the list of AH, BH,... (they are `.sp` files).

I am stuck with this list. Then having this list, I would like to apply an R script for a specific file name, for `AH`, then `BH`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I have tried it, bit the result is AH#1, AH#2,...BH#1, BH#2... but I wanted only AH, BH,... This was helpful... Moreover, do you know how to apply a R script to the list of these prefix. For example, I would like to apply a script to a file called 'nomfic', with 'nomfic' being each prefix of the prefvious list (as AH, then BH,...) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sub('(.*)#.*','\\1',list.files(your_directory_path))
```

Example:

```
sub('(.*)#.*','\\1',c('AB#1','AH#45'))
[1] "AB" "AH"
```

To apply your script to the result ( though generally we use file names) you do something lie this :

```
nomfic<- sub('(.*)#.*','\\1',list.files(your_directory_path))
lapply(nonfic, function(x){your_script})
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but here's what I propose:

```
prefix_letters <- c("AH", "BH")
prefix_numbers <- gsub(" ", "0", format(1:45, digits=2))
m <- outer(prefix_letters, prefix_numbers, function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep="#"))
l <- data.frame(t(m))
names(l) <- prefix_letters
head(l)

     AH    BH
1 AH#01 BH#01
2 AH#02 BH#02
3 AH#03 BH#03
4 AH#04 BH#04
5 AH#05 BH#05
6 AH#06 BH#06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sub` function to replace the irrelevant part of the strings with the empty string:

```
vec <- c("AH#01", "AH#02", "AH#45", "BH#01", "BH#02")

sub("#.*" , "", vec)
# [1] "AH" "AH" "AH" "BH" "BH"
```